# What does "unable to bind wire" error mean?

Tags: verilog

I have written the code below. It is for just one display segment, in this case 'e'. I used http://www.edaplayground.com/ for trying to simulate it; however, I get this error every time I try to run it:

> testbench.sv:13: error: Unable to bind wire/reg/memory Seg_e in
> `Seg_e_testbench' 1 error(s) during elaboration. Exit code expected:
> 0, received: 1

```
module Seg_e (
output reg seg,
input [3: 0] BCD
);


parameter ZERO = 1'b0;
parameter ONE = 1'b1;

always @ (BCD)
    case (BCD)
    0: seg = ONE;
    1: seg = ZERO;
    2: seg = ONE;
    3: seg = ZERO;
    4: seg = ZERO;
    5: seg = ZERO;
    6: seg = ONE;
    7: seg = ZERO;
    8: seg = ONE;
    9: seg = ZERO;
default: seg = ZERO;
endcase
  
endmodule

module Seg_e_testbench;


wire seg;
reg [3: 0] BCD;

parameter ZERO = 1'b0;
parameter ONE = 1'b1;

initial #250 $finish;

initial fork
  begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1,Seg_e);
  end
  
    #10 BCD = 0;
    #20 BCD = 1;
    #30 BCD = 2;
    #40 BCD = 3;
    #50 BCD = 4;
    #60 BCD = 5;
    #70 BCD = 6;
    #80 BCD = 7;
    #90 BCD = 8;
    #100 BCD = 9;

join
    Seg_e M0 (seg, BCD);


endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the module *instance* name, not the module name in the `$dumpvars` statement:

```
$dumpvars(1, M0);
```

Refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2012, section "21.7.1.2 Specifying variables to be dumped ($dumpvars)".

Answer (score -2):

You are supposed to give either module instance name or module name of testbench (**Seg_e_testbench**) and not the module name of design.

http://www.referencedesigner.com/tutorials/verilog/verilog_62.php